# Multithreading on multiple core/processors

Tags: multithreading, mutex

I get the idea that if locking and unlocking a mutex is an atomic operation, it can protect the critical section of code in case of a single processor architecture.
Any thread, which would be scheduled first, would be able to "lock" the mutex in a single machine code operation.
But how are mutexes any good when the threads are running on multiple cores? (Where different threads could be running at the same time on different "cores" at the same time).
I can't seem to grasp the idea of how a multithreaded program would work without any deadlock or race condition on multiple cores?

Comment: _"I can't seem to grasp the idea of how a multithreaded program would work without any deadlock or race condition on multiple cores?"_ -- why not? Your question is very unclear, and the mechanisms behind thread signaling objects (like a mutex) are considerably involved, making any detailed explanation of them too broad for a Stack Overflow question anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The general answer:

Mutexes are an operating system concept. An operating system offering mutexes has to ensure that these mutexes work correctly on all hardware that this operation system wants to support. If implementing a mutex is not possible for a specific hardware, the operating system cannot offer mutexes on that hardware. If the operating system requires the existence of mutexes to work correctly, it cannot support that hardware at all. How the operating system is implementing mutexes for a specific hardware is unsurprisingly very hardware dependent and varies a lot between the operating systems and their supported hardware.

The detailed answer:

Most general purpose CPUs offer atomic operations. These operations are designed to be atomic across all CPU cores within a system, whether these cores are part of a single or multiple individual CPUs.

With as little as two atomic operations, `atomic_or` and `atomic_and`, it is possible to implement a lock. E.g. think of

`int atomic_or ( int * addr, int val )`

It atomically calculates `*addr = *addr | val` and returns the old value of `*addr` prior to performing the calculation. If `*lock == 0` and multiple threads call `atomic_or(lock, 1)`, then only one of them will get `0` as result; only the first thread to perform that operation. All other threads get `1` as result. The one thread that got `0` is the winner, it has the lock, all other threads register for an event and go to sleep.

The winner thread now has exclusive access to the section following the `atomic_or`, it can perform the desired work and once it is done, it just clears the lock again (`atomic_and(lock, 0)`) and generates a system event, that the lock is now available again.

The system will then wake up one, some, or all of the threads that registered for this event before going to sleep and the race for the lock starts all over. Either one of the woken up threads will win the race or possibly none of them, as another thread was even faster and may have grabbed the lock in between the `atomic_and` and before the other threads were even woken up but that is okay and still correct, as it's still only one thread having access. All threads that failed to obtain the lock go back to sleep.

Of course, the actual implementations of modern systems are often much more complicated than that, they may take things like threads priorities into account (high prio threads may be preferred in the lock race) or might ensure that every thread waiting for a mutex will eventually also get it (precautions exist that prevent a thread from always losing the lock-race). Also mutexes can be recursive, in which case the system ensures that the same thread can obtain the same mutex multiple times without deadlocking and this requires some additional bookkeeping.

Probably needless to say but atomic operations are more expensive operations as they require the cores within a system to synchronize their work and this will slow their processing throughput. They may be somewhat expensive if all cores run on a single CPU but they may even be very expensive if there are multiple CPUs as the synchronization must take place over the CPU bus system that connects the CPUs with each other and this bus system usually does not operate at CPU speed level.

On the other hand, using mutexes will always slow down processing to begin with as providing exclusive access to resources has to slow down processing if multiple threads ever require access at the same time to continue their work. So for implementing mutexes this is irrelevant. Actually, if you can implement a function in a thread-safe way using just atomic operations instead of full featured mutexes, you will quite often have a noticeable speed benefit, despite these operations being more expensive than normal operations.

Answer (score 1):

Threads are managed by the operating system, which among other things, is responsible for scheduling threads to cores, so it can also avoid scheduling a specific thread onto a core.

A mutex is an operating-system concept. You're basically asking the OS to block a thread until some other thread tells the OS it's ok

Answer (score 0):

On modern operating systems, threads are an abstraction over the physical hardware. A programmer targets the thread as an abstraction for code execution. There is no separate abstraction for working on a hardware core available. The operating system is responsible for mapping threads to physical cores.

A mutex is a data structure that lives in system memory. Any thread that has access can read that memory position, regardless of what thread or core it is running in. It doesn't matter whether your code is executing on core 1 or 20, its still has the ability to read the current state of the lock.

In other words, regardless of the number of threads or cores, there is only shared system memory for them to act on.